# Undefined reference to callback function in subscriber

Tags: ros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use callback inside a class, is this possible for indigo version ?

I have double and triple checked my syntax and I have run out of ideas why the compiler complains, undefined reference to foo::callback

any advice on where to look would be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246174/undefined-reference-to-callback-function-in-subscriber/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-10-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-21**:
This is definitely possible, and Indigo has not changed anything wrt this.

`crystal.ball.net` is down at the moment, could you please include a C++ snippet that shows your callback method, and where you instantiate your subscriber? And your `CMakeLists.txt`, seeing as you post a linker error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoom thank you for insisting it would be a syntax issue. After trying to find the bug and staring at the screen it just turns out that in my member function definition instead of void foo::callback(..) I just had void callback( .. ). I kept looking at the subscriber syntax. *facepalm

---

Originally posted by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) with karma: 54 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0